# How to get values of two observables at a time which listen to http.get?

Tags: angular

I have written small application which gets data from two tables in mySQL via PHP pages: getRow.php and getColumn.php.

I successfully read content of those tables if done separately (when I comment on or another), but when I try to get them both there is an error 'Cannot read property '1' of undefined'.

As a result values of thoes arrays are blank. Suprisingly the length of those arrays seems correct.

ngOnIinit listens to the values of those arrays. getRow and getColumn collects values from mySQL via php pages as mentioned.

```
export class Row {
public id: number;
public title: string;
public sequence: number;
constructor(
  id: number,
  title: string,
  sequence: number) {
    this.id = id;
    this.title = title;
    this.sequence = sequence;
  }
  }

rows: Row[];
row: Row;
columns: Row[];  
column: Row[];


ngOnInit() {       
 forkJoin(this.DbService.getRow(this.idBoard),
    this.DbService.getColumn(this.idBoard)
    ).subscribe(val => {

      this.rows = val[0].slice();
      this.columns = val[1].slice();
      this.rowNumber = this.rows.length;
      this.columnNumber = this.columns.length;
    });
}
```

If I comment the line 'this.columns = val[1].slice();' it works fine but only one array. The similar behaviour if I comment the line 'this.rows = val[0].slice();'.

```
getRow(): Observable<Row[]> {
  return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/getrow`).pipe(
    map((res) => {

        this.rows = res['data'];
        return this.rows;
    }),
    catchError(this.handleError));
}

getColumn(): Observable<Row[]> {
  return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/getcolumn`).pipe(
    map((res) => {

        this.rows = res['data'];
        return this.rows;
    }),
    catchError(this.handleError));
}
```

As a result I would like to have rows[] and columns[] filled with proper values.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your forkjoin:

```
  this.rows = val[0]['data'].slice();
  this.columns = val[1]['data'].slice();
```

Regards

Comment: thanks for the advice, but when I replaced it as you suggested, it gives an error: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined at SafeSubscriber._next (app.component.ts:75)

Comment: Would you post server response example? Thanks

Comment: Do you mean sql query result? {"data":[{"id":"1","title":"to do","sequence":"0"},{"id":"2","title":"analize","sequence":"1"},{"id":"3","title":"test","sequence":"2"},{"id":"4","title":"done","sequence":"3"}]} for rows. and for columns {"data":[{"id":"5","title":"phase 1","sequence":"0"},{"id":"6","title":"phase 2","sequence":"1"}]}

Comment: In your getColumn method the object returned is this.rows. Shouldn't this be columns?

Comment: Thanks, but not. I did not mention the getRow and getColumn are in another component and they both extract data from the same sql array.

Comment: On the other hand I have found the solution. Sorry for bothering you. The problem was with proper array generation and then displaying in html. Not with observables.